# Spread VirtualBox VMs over cores

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, multi-core

I am using many VirtualBox VMs with different OS on one Ubuntu Linux host for development. Sometimes my scripts get wrong and starts loading 100% of VM cpu. And when one VM loads 100% cpu I cant even use host system - it's slow!

Then I have to open top (very slowly), see that VirtualBox process is using 240% of CPU, then open every VM window until I find the VM that loads cpu and kill process. I don't want to kill whole VirtualBox process that is using much cpu.

All my VMs are configured to use only one cpu core, with execution cap 100%. My cpu is AMD FX 8370 (8 cores, 16 threads), my host runs on SSD raid 10 with filesystems correctly aligned. Am I in windows host environment? Of course not! So why do I experience slowdowns?

Maybe because all VirtualBox VM get only first core assigned (like windows usually do)? How to check that and how to make each VM use each core? Maybe some other guessworks?

Maybe this question is just: How to assign any app to specific core in Linux?

Comment: Why don't you give the VM more than 1 CPU in the settings? I think this relieves the host single CPUs, too

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I thought that if I give it all cores it will load all cores instead of one core....

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think assigning more cores distributes the traffic of the VM to the amount of selected cores

Comment: Sorry for posting an answer which is not an answer, but at least, while you wait for a full answer, I can make your work easier. Cheers.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I will test that configuration, but previously I read the experience where assigning more than 1 core to guest VM actually made guest VM slower. So I would rather like to spread single core VMs over host cores rather then allow any VM to full 100% cpu of host.

Comment: Pls read my edit, **perhaps** I have the solution for you (not sure, though, that this is really what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have an answer to your question, but at least I can relieve your pain.

If you start each VM from the command line, for instance like

```
VBoxManage startvm Name_of_VM --type headless
```

then the top command with the option `-c` will display also the full command which started the process. This way you can immediately identify the culprit process, and kill it with the `k` option inside `top` itself (you will have to to provide the number of the process you want to kill,which you have just identified).

**The good thing is**, this works even if you start all of your VMs from the GUI, not from the CLI.

EDIT:

On second thought, perhaps I know the answer to your question. I am not sure this is really what you are searching for, in this case pls just tell me so.

The Linux utility to confine execution of a process to a pre-specified core is `taskset`. You should have it by default, if not check the package `util-linux`. You can display the process *affinity* (*i.e.*, the list of cpus on which it is allowed to run) by means of

```
      taskset -cp Process_ID
```

(the `p` flag specifies that what follows is a process number, the `c` flag substitutes a character string to the hexadecimal representation of CPU cores which would be the default).

You can assign an already running process to run only on cores 0 and 1, for instance, by means of

```
     taskset -cp 0,1 Process_ID
```

or launch a new program on core 0 only by means of:

```
      taskset -c 0 VBoxManage startvm Name_of_VM --type headless
```

Two caveats: first, the fact that you have confined the process to run on a single CPU does not mean it will be the only process running on it: all processes whose affinity includes that CPU will run, for some fraction of the time, on it. If you want to reserve a given CPU for the exclusive use of a process which you set with `taskset`, you will have to use the parameter `isolcpus` which [isolates the given CPU from the kernel scheduler](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re46.html). Just add the parameter isolcpus=[cpu_number] to the Linux kernel command line for the boot loader.

Also, you should be advised that confining a process to a single CPU need not be the `total solution` that you seem to think. CPUs use peripherals of any sort and, under given circumstances, they may get stuck because the peripheral in question becomes unavailable, which causes the CPU to loop in its requests, and the bus and perhaps also the peripheral become overloaded with the requests. An example? I use the Sonos controller running under Wine; when I activate a VPN, it becomes disconnected from its home base in California, and keeps flooding my system with network requests. This has nothing to do with confinement to a single CPU.

Comment: Thanks! my life is a lot easier now! :) Will wait for real answer now, because 1 VM should not slowdown the whole host system.

Comment: Thanks! So I would just write script that spreads VMs over cores with this command. Will see if this helps.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I made working a script based on your solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the help of MariusMatutiae's answer I finally managed to write the "spreader" script that spreads all launched virtualbox VMs to different cores. Moreover it also does the same thing with VMware VMs.

To use this script all your VMs should be single-cored (that can be set in settings). Otherwise you can exclude them by modifying grep regexp.

```
#!/bin/bash

#getting possible affinity lists
AFFINITY=($(taskset -cp 1 | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\)\+[-]\([0-9]\+\).*/\1 \2/'))

echo Detected min_cpu: ${AFFINITY[0]}, max_cpu: ${AFFINITY[1]}.

CURRENT_AFFINITY=${AFFINITY[1]};

ps -Af | grep -i "[V]irtualBox.*comment\|.*[.]vm[x]" | awk -F" " '{ print $2}' |

# Iterating backwards because I think that farther cpus are less loaded. Maybe I am wrong
while read pid
do
    echo Setting $pid to cpu $CURRENT_AFFINITY
    taskset -cp $CURRENT_AFFINITY $pid


    #loop stuff
    let CURRENT_AFFINITY=CURRENT_AFFINITY-1;
    if [[ "$CURRENT_AFFINITY" -lt ${AFFINITY[0]} ]];
    then
        CURRENT_AFFINITY=${AFFINITY[1]};
    fi
done
```

If you want to make it work only with VirutalBox VMs then remove `[V]irtualBox.*comment\|` from grep pattern. If you want to make it work only with VMware VMs, remove `\|.*[.]vm[x]` from grep pattern.

Just after applying this script you can see some lags in all VMs for several seconds. Then everything becomes good and works as expected.

Now VMs can't eat my cpu even when overloaded, and firefox is really happy to eat it all. But that's another story... :/